# Rounding corners of image inside KivyMD Card

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I wanted to add elevation effect on an image. So I basically added it inside an MDCard. Now the image looks fine but I want to make the corners of image rounded. So, I tried making corners of MDCard rounded, but the image just sticks out of the box when fully stretched.

It looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to have rounded corners like this but image fully stretched
[image]

But when I stretch image, the image corners cover the rounded corners of MDCard
Here's the part of code that I'm using:

```
    song_image = AsyncImage(source=self.image_url, pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}, allow_stretch=True)
    card = MDCard(orientation='vertical', border_radius= 20, radius= [15], pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.65}, size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.size[0]*0.9, Window.size[0]*0.9))
    card.add_widget(song_image)
    self.details_screen.add_widget(card)
```

Any idea how to do this? or any other way to make rounded corners with elevation without the use of kivyMD card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd import images_path
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

Builder.load_string(
    '''
<Card>:
    elevation: 10
    radius: [36, ]

    FitImage:
        id: bg_image
        source: "images/bg.png"
        size_hint_y: .35
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        radius: [36, 36, 0, 0, ]
''')


class Card(MDCard):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        modal = ModalView(
            size_hint=(0.4, 0.8),
            background=f"{images_path}/transparent.png",
            overlay_color=(0, 0, 0, 0),
        )
        modal.add_widget(Card())
        modal.open()


Example().run()
```

Comment: I tried it but still the image don't have round corners. only the MDCard has round corners so when image fits the card it just covers the corner and it no longer looks round

Comment: Update KivyMD library from master branch.

Comment: can you explain how to update it in my buildozer.spec file? When exporting buildozer is using the pip version i guess. I tried writing KivyMD==... but got error saying version not found. I even downloaded the folder and gave the path to custom requirements but i guess i did something wrong as its not detecting it. I also rebuilt the whole apk by deleting .builder

Comment: `requirements=kivy, git+https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git@master, ...`

Comment: After using the latest version I have lost the icons. Do I have to include something else to get icons?